# Alternative to multitouch in Mavericks

Tags: macos, trackpad, multi-touch

I am using OSX Mavericks on latest Mackbook Pro Retina.
After a week of intensive usage I have got some pain in my fingers because of the multi-fingers scrolling (two to scroll pages, three to switch between screens).

How can I scroll in applications without using 2 fingers-scroll? I know I can press 'Fn+Up/Down' in web-browsers, but how to scroll in Finder, Terminal, etc.? 
Is there also any way to switch between virtual screens without using three-fingers?

PS: when scrolling using multi-touch, one has to keep 2 fingers floating over the surface of the trackpad - this after some time leads to the pain. On iPad it doesn't happen because its position is usually not vertical (when you keep it in another hand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch between screens using the **Ctrl+Right/Left Arrow** shortcuts (by default, this can be of course modified in the Keyboard Shortcuts settings).

You can scroll in the terminal using **Shift+PgUp/PgDn** keys. On MacBooks you will need to press **Shift+Fn+Up/Down Arrow**.

**Fn+Up/Down** also works in Finder.

Answer (score 0):

In some programs (e.g. Safari) you can use **Alt+Up/Down** to scroll up and down. I find it more convenient since it only requires one hand.

In Finder this shortcut seems to jump from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and found Apple's magic mouse helped a lot. You can still use almost all of Maverick's gestures but I find its much easier and more comfortable. Try it out. If it doesn't help you can return it for a refund. (check Apple's return policies in your area)